# need to grab few things from a file described below

Tags: perl

```
ask_question MC16_Phase2 :  3156 occurences (100.00%) : module abc_testbench/abc_top_0/abc**
```

This statement is in a file. There are multiple entries of this statement and other stuff is also present. I need to read it from there and put it in another file in the following manner:

```
3156 abc_testbench/abc_top_0/abc**
```

Fixed entities in that statement are:

```
ask_question
occurences
module
```

could you please more elaborate the statement. i am new in perl, could you please make me understand the whole scenario from the very beginning starting from reading the file to grabbing the things in the given manner. Thanks Ray Toal.

Comment: Your question statement doesn't match the title - it mentions selecting material from the input, not sorting.

Answer (score 2):

You will want a regex with two capturing groups.  Based on the information given, the regex would be:

```
/ask_question[^:]*:\s*(\d+)\s*occurences[^:*]:\s*module\s*([^*]*\*\*)/
```

Apply this regex throughout the input, and write the captures, separated by a space, to your output file.